# Circular design in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am facing a difficulty making a circular shape in Illustrator. When I duplicate a given shape in circular design and make as many duplicates as required, the last object stands out. I have tried arranging the shape to go backward and the next objects come forwards. But to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. An image might help explain what your problem is. Could you also explain a bit more about what functions you used to do the duplication? Thanks!

Comment: Am i right in guessing that what you mean is not problems with circles as such; but that you want your duplicates to arrange _behind_ each other, rather than _in front_?

Comment: Could use a blend and simply reverse the spine.. but without an example it's really impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pushing the last object backwards, pull the first object all the way forwards, to the front.

Use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Or in Menus with mouse:

<kbd>Object > Arrange > Bring to Front</kbd>

I think you're pushing the last object back one position at a time, but that will take too long when you have many objects arranged in a circle.